# awk math - getting natural numbers

Tags: awk

I have two columns:

```
100011780   100016332  
10100685    10105465      
101190948   101195542  
101286838   101288018  
101411746   101413662  
101686767   101718138  
101949793   101950504  
101989424   101993757  
102095320   102106147  
102133372   102143125
```

I want to get the middle value of those numbers.
Tried to:

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2-$1}' input | awk '{print $1"\t"$2/2}' | awk '{print $1+$2}' > output
```

But some numbers after the division by 2 aren't natural anymore and probably of that my output is like this :

```
100014056
10103075
101193245
101287428
101412704
1.01702e+08
1.0195e+08
1.01992e+08
1.02101e+08
1.02138e+08
```

Maybe it's possible to locate non natural value and -/+ 0.5 to make it natural?

Comment: Middle = median, center, ... ?

Comment: Center - value exactly in between of those numbers.

Comment: "Those numbers" means what? The first number in the left list and the first number in the right? I look at the number `100018608` (first number in the bottom list) and don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry John, I edited the output I am getting. I want to get the number in the center of the columns (those numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly don't need to call awk 3 times to get the average of two numbers.

```
awk '{printf("%d\n", ($1+$2)/2)}' input
```

Use `printf()` to control the output.

```
100014056
10103075
101193245
101287428
101412704
101702452
101950148
101991590
102100733
102138248
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add, and use, this round function in your AWK file:

```
function round(x) {
    ival = int(x);

    if (ival == x)
            return x;

    if (x < 0) {
            aval = -x;
            ival = int(aval);
            fraction = aval - ival;
            if (fraction >= .5)
                    return int(x) - 1;
            else
                    return int(x);
    } else {
            fraction = x - ival;
            if (fraction >= .5)
                    return ival + 1;
            else
                    return ival;
    }
}
```

For example, the avg value will be:

```
{print round(($1+$2)/2)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want when the sum is uneven, but you could do all in one go:

```
gawk '{printf "%i\n", ($1 + $2) / 2}' input
```

What you are looking for are [format control options](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters) to printf.